# Highcharts and CSV, timestamps on x axis

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I'm displaying graphs from CSV with Highcharts,
The data has a unix timestamp as first field that I display on the x axis.
Everything is fine with my first dataset, and it displays properly, with the dates converted as it should be eg: wed 1st Aug 2013 00:00:00

now the issue :

When I load another of the sets, the graph still displays, but the dates on the x-axis look like 00:00:00.001. all the files are formatted the same...

EVEN STRANGER !!
If I remove a few lines (3) from my working dataset, I'm having the same problem! i checked the line breaks and pretty much everything I could think of, to no avail... An idea?

Material :  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gmqpsjd910va45l/8dJr_hLkHB

I've uploaded the following :

screenshots of working and not working graph, working dataset, and the same with the last 3 lines cut off, as well as my index.html code. Hope it will help, but I'll add whatever you need to give me a hand on this thing.

Peace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All unix timestamps, should be multiplied by 1000 to achieve javascript timestamps.

Comment: mm, thought I answered my own question, must be a SO bug. Yes, it was teh issue, but it stills doesn't explain the weird behaviour of my dataset.